# vertically fill space, with in display: table-cell (IE8/9)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i have a nested display table in a display table cell and i doesnt seem to apply the 100% height to IE 8 or 9 (even a extra containing div wont work), works fine in all other major browsers, here the jsfiddle it should explain everything.

http://jsfiddle.net/bDm4d/12/
 try that in firefox/chrome/safari to see how it should look and check in ie8/9 youll understand the issue. Both columns should be equal height, since they are both with in a display table cell. The center (green in the right, pink in the left) have height to auto so it "should expand" like it does in webkit/ff.

A work around for ie would be great conditional or not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, display: table-cell isn't supported by IE. Luckily, there are several workarounds to get divs with display: block to fill the height of their parents, creating the 'equal height' effect. I found [this article](http://positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight) to be very helpful when I was faced with a similar layout challenge. Good luck!